# How to store a remote word list into a personal file?

Tags: python

Here is the error message I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "datalister.py", line 10, in <module>
    wordlist.write(words)
TypeError: expected a string or other character buffer object
```

My code:

```
import random, sys
from urllib import urlopen
word_url = "http://scrapmaker.com/data/wordlists/dictionaries/rockyou.txt"
words = []

for word in urlopen(word_url).readlines():
    print "Doing it now..."
    wordlist = open('wordlist.txt', 'w')
    wordlist.write(words)
    wordlist.close()
    print "File written successfully!"
```

Comment: What is happening now in that code that is not meeting your expectation. What do you expect the result to be?

Comment: *Can I [something]?*  Seems like the answer to that question is easily obtained through trial and error. Did you *try* it?

Comment: Can you? Probably. Will you? That's your choice.

Comment: I did try it buddy but it ran for ages then returned this...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you accurately describe the problem.  We're not a testing service -- show the output you got, and what you expected.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "datalister.py", line 10, in <module>
    wordlist.write(words)
TypeError: expected a string or other character buffer object

Comment: Edit that information into the main body of the question.

Comment: I expected to get every word in the link to a text file my apologies i am new here.

Comment: Click [here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42935465/edit) and *edit* your question.

Comment: NB; `words` is an empty list. You're trying to *write* that list, on every iteration. Also, you're repetitively opening the file for each `word in ...readlines()`.

Comment: I knew something was going on in the for loop thank you, friend I shall rewrite it now to put that logic into context.

Comment: When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.

Answer (score 1):

The error is exactly what it says: you have to give **write** a string, not a list.  You're one letter off: you need to write **word**, not **words**.  That simple change fixes the program ... I think.  It's running nicely for me.

```
wordlist = open('wordlist.txt', 'w')
for word in urlopen(word_url):
    print "Doing it now..."
    wordlist.write(word)
    print "File written successfully!"
wordlist.close()
```

Since it's one word per line, you don't really need to read in the entire file before you start writing things; just use the default generator to grab the lines as you need them.

Also, note that you never put anything in to the list **words**.  If all you want is the word list, you may as well remove that variable.

Comment: This will open 'wordlist.txt' each time through the loop and overwrite its previous contents. Even if it didn't, the file would end up with only one word in it.

Comment: I love this site already I overlooked the whole thing to much, and again thank you for all the help people!

Comment: Probably also need to use `wordlist.write(word + '\n')`.

Comment: Good thought, but the words are read with the newline attached; the write includes it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code i got to work have a try:

```
import random, sys
from urllib import urlopen
word_url = "http://scrapmaker.com/data/wordlists/dictionaries/rockyou.txt"
wordlist = open('wordlist.txt', 'w')
for word in urlopen(word_url):
    print "Added: ", word
    wordlist.write(word)

print "Successfully written all words to file!"
wordlist.close()
```

Comment: Now to differentiate your reply: what does this demonstrate that earlier answers did not?

Comment: Just another version of the same answer in readable form for others.